# infimum of superfunctions is harmonic proof

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Can you please help me with this exercise? Let $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be an open, bounded domain and let $\Phi$ be a bounded function on $\partial{U}$. Let $S^\Phi$ denote the set of superfunctions relative to $\Phi$, that is $S^\Phi =\{v \in C^0(\bar{U}): v$ is superharmonic and $v \geq \Phi$ on $\partial{U}$ }.
Show that the function $u(x)=\inf_{v \in S^\Phi} v(x)$ is harmonic.
Hint: you are allowed to use the following statement: Let $S_\Phi =\{v \in C^0(\bar{U}): v$ is subharmonic and $v \leq \Phi$ on $\partial{U}$ } then the function $u(x)=\sup_{v \in S_\Phi} v(x)$ is harmonic.

Comment: Flip signs. Then just use the statement you are allowed to use.

Comment: You can also Google "Perron's method".

Comment: @Michał Miśkiewicz  I don't think I'm learning very much if I just flip the signs.  I'm reading a proof for the sup which I found online (online you just find the sup proof, and nowhere the inf proof) under "Perron's method" and trying to repeat the argument for the inf but i'm very confused. Could you maybe post a proof for the inf? It would help me a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $v \in C^0(\bar{U})$, then 
$$ v \text{ is superharmonic} \iff -v \text{ is subharmonic,} $$
$$ v \ge \Phi \text{ on } \partial U \iff -v \le -\Phi \text{ on } \partial U. $$
This shows that 
$$ v \in S^\Phi \iff -v \in S_{-\Phi}, $$
hence the function 
$$ u(x) = \inf_{v \in S^\Phi} v(x) = \inf_{v \in S_{-\Phi}} -v(x) = - \sup_{v \in S_{-\Phi}} v(x) $$
is harmonic.

---

As indicated by the equivalence above, the proofs for $S_\Phi$ and $S^\Phi$ are exactly symmetric and you shouldn't find any difficulty in translating one into the other.

Nevertheless, Perron's method for $S^\Phi$ is described e.g. in P. Lindqvist's *Notes on the p-Laplace equation*, available [on his website](https://folk.ntnu.no/lqvist/lecturenotes.html).